# Is there any way to colorized MacBook pro terminal?

Tags: terminal, macbook, colors, macbook-pro, color-profiles

I use Ubuntu Os and when I use terminal I can differentiate what is folder what is file or what is a directory because they have different color scale. For example directories are green or working sh or csh files appears in green color.

So when I use my MacBook pro terminal its hard to understand what is folder what is file etc. Is there any way to color MacBook terminal ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. There is a multitude of ways. For `ls` check the man page and see whenever it supports `--color`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Add `export CLICOLOR=1` to the appropriate shell startup script, such as `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: thank you so much :)